# Android navigation drawer reorder items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm facing an weird behaviour of navigation drawer so if someone can help...
I have a navigation drawer filled by an adapter (like list of Object : title and icon).

In Activity

```
 mNavItems = NavBarUtil.listItem(); // List of object
 mBinding.navList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems));
```

The view for drawer is just a simple ListView.

The weird behaviour is that when the keyboard appears (whatever it comes), the order of the items in navigationDrawer change... it's like, displaying the keyboard recalculate all the view.
Just wanna precise that all listener for item work fine, the issue is just about the view like icon and title...

Thanks you guys